# Is $\Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z $ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z $?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Is $\Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z $ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z $?

my reasoning for thinking this isn't the case is that the first group has an element of order 6 whereas the second doesn't.

Comment: $(1,1,0)$ is of order $6$.

Comment: This is an obvious consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem for details.

Comment: @Crostul well, that may not be altogether helpful to the user, who is asking about group isomorphisms (in the tags). It seems like overkill anyway

Comment: Ah of course, thank you!

Comment: @TheProblem Please use markup to clearly write the math part. You can see what I did by clicking the edit timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: the element $(1,1,1)$ of the latter group has order $30$, so the latter group is a cyclic group of order $30$.